# While loop terminates only in one iterartion

Tags: java, database

```
try { 
       ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from details where COURSEANDDEPT='"+username+"'");
        //if (rs.next()) {    
            while (rs.next()) {
                String logid=rs.getString(1);
                char temp=' ';
                ResultSet ag=stat.executeQuery("select type from login");
                if (ag.next()) {
                    temp=ag.getString(1).charAt(0);
                    if (temp=='s' || temp=='S') {
                        String logid=ag.getString(1);
                        stat.executeQuery("insert into assignments values('"+logid+"','"+comments+"','P','"+userid+"','"+username+"')");
                    }
                }  
            }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Assignment Sent To The Whole Class");
            //} else {
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Invalid Branch");
            //}
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Assignments.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The while loop of rs.next() terminates only in one iteration even after containing 6 records in itself. How to rectify it?

Comment: `if rs.next { while rs.next {}}` will always skip the first record. Not likely to cause skipping of five but it's something you should be aware of. Ditch the `if` bit altogether since it's naturally subsumed into the `while`.

Comment: RS.next() returns false thus exiting the while loop.

Comment: @marshal craft isn't it obvious if condition becomes false it will terminate...haha

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use the same statement object for executing several queries. Addictional problems are

- you don't close neither your statements neither your resultsets (see example).
- you should use statements' parameters (see example).
- you should not use select *, but list the columns you want back from statement (i'll not include this in the example).
- one of the queries ("select type from login") is always repeated the same way, maybe there's an error on the query. Otherwise it should be executed once outside the main loop.
- in the example i don't manage the connection but this should be done too

Lets suppose that you have a Connection object called conn

```
  PreparedStatemet stat=null;
  PreparedStatement innerStat=null;
  PreparedStatement insertStat=null;

  try { 
     stat=conn.prepareStatement("select * from details where COURSEANDDEPT=?");
     stat.setString(1,username);

     ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery();
     //if (rs.next()) {    
        while (rs.next()) {
            String logid=rs.getString(1);
            char temp=' ';
            innerStat=conn.prepareStatement("select type from login");
            ResultSet ag=innerStat.executeQuery();

            if (ag.next()) {
                temp=ag.getString(1).charAt(0);
                if (temp=='s' || temp=='S') {
                    String logid=ag.getString(1);
                    ag.close();
                    innerStat.close();
                    insertStat=conn.prepareStatement("insert into assignments values(?,?,?,?,?)");
                    insertStat.setString(1,logId);
                    insertStat.setString(2,comments);
                    insertStat.setString(3,"P");
                    insertStat.setString(4,userid);
                    insertStat.setString(5,username);

                    insertStat.executeUpdate();
                    insertStat.close();


                }//closes if on temp
            }  //closes if on ag
        } //closes while
        rs.close();
        stat.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Assignment Sent To The Whole Class");
        //} else {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Invalid Branch");
        //}
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Assignments.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     if(insertStat!=null) insertStat.close();
     if(innerStat!=null) innertStat.close();
     if(stat!=null) stat.close();
 }
```

Comment: For added protection, you could use try-with-resource, it'll make it cleaner, but otherwise, good ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that each connection can only handle one SQL statement at a time.  You're trying to leave your first `select` statement open while you do a bunch of other statements.  You can't do this on a single connection.

I suggest two changes to make this work.

- Do the query against the `login` table first.  Its result won't vary from one iteration to the next, so there is no point in repeating it over and over within the main loop.
- Rewrite the queries against `details` and `assignments` as an insert/select statement.  It's probably something like the following.

.

```
"insert into assignments " +
"select logid,  ,'" + comments + "','P','" + userid + "','" + username + "' "
"from details " +
"where COURSEANDDEPT='"+username+"'"
```

Also,  you might consider writing this with a `PreparedStatement`, depending on whether SQL injection attacks are a likelihood.